# Error connecting to MySQL from pipe file

Tags: mysql, pipe

I have a website with MySQL DB set up and functioning correctly.

I am also piping mail to a script on the server, which also needs to connect to the same DB.

This was all working correctly until last week, when I started getting connection error messages back from the pipe script.

I am using exactly the same credentials to connect the pipe script as on the regular PHP site pages.

e.g. Server: localhost, username XXXX password XXXX

However I keep getting:

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in...

If I include the port e.g. localhost::3306, I get 
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '3306'

If i switch the server to use the IP address instead, then it seems to connect to the server but fails on authentication: 
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user ...

It's identical connection details and when running the PHP script through the browser, it works. It just won't connect when it is run directly by the system as a pipe script.

Could anyone shed any light on what the problem might be?

Thank you!

Comment: what kind of script is it? is it using the command line mysql client?

Comment: Hello - it's a PHP script

Comment: Have you figured this out?  I think I'm having the same problem.